# Kaggle says "Permission denied" when trying to create a dataset

Tags: kaggle

I'm trying to upload a dataset to Kaggle, It's a csv file. I keep getting a "Permissions denied" error. I've tried different licenses and tested different files.

I also tried using GitHub link instead, didn't work. Can't find anything on how to fix this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**(in my case)** To upload the public dataset a Kaggle account needs a **mobile number** added.

You can try these steps.

1. Upload the dataset as private
2. Change the visibility to public from the settings tab
3. It will ask for your mobile number. Verify mobile number and done!